# react carousel not wrapping content correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap carousel to try and display a list of items within a carousel. However these don't seem to appear on the page. The carousel works fine if I pass in the Carousel.Items directly in the same class but I want to wrap the CustomerCard class items sot that I can return a list of items that now will appear in the carousel. Any ideas?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { customerProduct } from '../data/CustomerProduct';
import Carousel from '../../node_modules/react-bootstrap/Carousel';

const CustomerCard = (props) => {

    const rows = props.customerProduct.map((row, index) => {
        return (
          
                <Carousel.Item key={index}>
                    <div className="customer-product-card-container">
                        <div className="columns">
                            <div className="column image-column">
                                <div className="image-wrapper">
                                    <img src={row.image} alt =""/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <div className="name-wrapper">
                                    <span className="name">{row.name}</span>
                                </div>                     
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                3
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <span className="price"><b>{row.price_from} - {row.price_to}</b></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>        
                </Carousel.Item>
        )
    })

    return [rows]
}


class Customers extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <section className="section main-section">
                <div className="main-wrapper">
                    <div className="customer-title-wrapper wood-font">
                        <h2 className="has-text-centered customer-title">Customers Also Brought</h2>
                    </div>  
                    <div className="customer-elements-wrapper">                    
                      <Carousel>
                        <CustomerCard customerProduct={customerProduct} />               
                      </Carousel>
                    </div>       
                </div>
                
            </section>
        )
    }
}

export default Customers
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but you return an array of arrays (`[rows]`). I might be able to help more if you can create a working example (codesandbox or something)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments I also think the problem might be that you are returning an array of arrays. It's hard to test your code as no working example is included but I tried to build it together my self.

I think a solution like this should solve your problem and a little bit more readability. Instead of having a `CustomerCard` component that returns a list of cards it just returns one card and you loop through the items inside of the `Customers` component instead.

```
import React from 'react'

import Carousel from '../../node_modules/react-bootstrap/Carousel'
import { customerProduct } from '../data/CustomerProduct'

const CustomerCard = ({ image, name, price_from, price_to }) => (
  <Carousel.Item>
    <div className="customer-product-card-container">
      <div className="columns">
        <div className="column image-column">
          <div className="image-wrapper">
            <img src={image} alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="column">
          <div className="name-wrapper">
            <span className="name">{name}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="column">3</div>
        <div className="column">
          <span className="price">
            <b>
              {price_from} - {price_to}
            </b>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Carousel.Item>
)

const Customers = () => (
  <section className="section main-section">
    <div className="main-wrapper">
      <div className="customer-title-wrapper wood-font">
        <h2 className="has-text-centered customer-title">Customers Also Brought</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="customer-elements-wrapper">
        <Carousel>
          {customerProduct.map((row) => (
            <CustomerCard key={row.SOME_UNIQUE_ATTRIBUTE} {...row} />
          ))}
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
)

export default Customers
```